# I am new to vue js ... can't display loaded data from a php file

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

Template part :

```
`<div class="col-sm-6" >
  <ul class="list-group" id="pos">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(itm, index) in items">
      <strong>{{index}} : {{ itm.sub }}</strong> - {{ itm.price }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

Script part :

```
new Vue({
    el: '#pos',
    http: {
        root: '/vuetest',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Basic YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk'
        }
    },
    data: {
        items: []               
    },

    created:function () {
        this.$http.get('index.php').then(function(resp,status,request){
            this.items = resp.data;
            console.log(this.items); // got data but not displayed in  browser
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

My Source files are from cdnjs.cloudeflare.com:

- vue.js (2.1.4)
- vue-resource.js (1.0.3).

Comment: I would stronly recommend to use ES6 and arrow functions as then you will be able to move away from `.bind(this)` and issues with `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `this` isn't `that`...

```
created:function () {
    this.$http.get('index.php').then(function(resp,status,request){
        this.items = resp.data; // this is referring to the current function, and not to vue's scope.
        console.log(this.items); // got data but not displayed in  browser
    }.bind(this));
}
```

So the correct use is:

```
created:function () {
    var self = this
    this.$http.get('index.php').then(function (resp,status,request) {
        self.items = resp.data;
        console.log(this.items);
    });
}
```

Comment: Working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As MU commented above, better you to use Arrows functions, so the "this" will have the scope you want.

```
mounted () {
}
```

Then you can access all your Data properties normally with "this".